# I am working on some project in Meteor, and want to insert some images in mongodb along with other information like genre, fixed rating etc

Tags: mongodb, meteor, insertion

I have used for loop to insert images, but other information mentioned can not be inserted independently for each movie. How can I insert all info. This is how my startup code look like.

If no images is present at start, then insert some images to mongodb and later read them.

```
Server file:    
Meteor.startup(() => {
        if(Images.find().count()==0)
        {
          for(var i=1; i<7; i++)
          {
            Images.insert(
            {
                img_src:"img_"+i+".jpg",
                img_alt:"Image number "+i
            })
          } 
        }
      }
```

I have also tried other way, but that didn't works. Look code below.

```
Server file:    
var img_data=[{
        img_src:"img_1.jpg",
        img_alt:"Borat"
        },
        {
          img_src:"img_2.jpg",
          img_alt:"Doctor Sleep"
        },
        {
          img_src:"img_3.jpg",
          img_alt:"The HAUNTING Of Hill House"
        }];
        
Images.insert({images:img_data});
```

**When i see inside collection, following output appears i.e. all images `img_data` is added as a single object, that is main problem.[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhdZa.png)**

The client side look like below.

```
Images.find({}, {sort:{rating:-1}})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhdZa.png)

Comment: `but other information mentioned can not be inserted independently for each movie` is there an error or why do you assume it's not possible? How do you expect to know that other information has been inserted? What is "other information"?

Comment: Please **see image output** attached above, **var img_data** appears as a single object instead of multiple images. And For loop can not be used to add different genre or rating.